# Marshal struct from C to C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

EDIT: I oversimplified my example... In the real code I was assigning values to strMyStringx without correctly using wcscpy_s, so instead of assigning the values I was just passing the pointer, which was out of scope by the time the values were being marshaled into managed code...

I'm trying to marshal a struct with three string properties from C to C#, but I can't get the definition of the struct right in C#. All of the properties print as garbage. Am I marshaling wrong or do my properties have the wrong type?

My custom structure:

```
typedef struct _MY_STRUCT_STRING {
    LPWSTR strMyString1;
    LPWSTR strMyString2;
    LPWSTR strMyString3;
}MY_STRUCT_STRING, *PMY_STRUCT_STRING;
```

My C function returns an array of pointers to this struct:

```
bool bEnumerateString(OUT LONG &i_arr_size, OUT PMY_STRUCT_STRING* &pArrStringStruct)
{
// [...] function simplified to demonstrate building a pointer to an array of struct*
long i_arr_size = 3

PMY_STRUCT_STRING *ptr_arr_string = (PMY_STRUCT_STRING *)malloc(sizeof(PMY_STRUCT_STRING)* i_arr_size);

for (int i = 0; i < i_arr_size; i++) {
    ptr_arr_string[i] = (PMY_STRUCT_STRING)malloc(sizeof(MY_STRUCT_STRING));
    ptr_arr_string[i]->strMyString1 = L"String 1"; // This would work. In the real code I was assigning values from another array and mistakenly passed the pointer rather than doing wcscpy_s
    ptr_arr_string[i]->strMyString2 = L"String 2";
    ptr_arr_string[i]->strMyString3 = L"String 3";
}

pArrStringStruct = ptr_arr_string;

return true;
}
```

C#:

```
    //Import the DLL with my function
    [DllImport("My.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "bEnumerateString")]
    internal static extern bool bEnumerateString(out long count, out IntPtr pArrStringStruct);

     // Define the C# equivalent of the C struct
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal struct MY_STRUCT_STRING
    {
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
        public string strMyString1;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
        public string strMyString1;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
        public string strMyString1;
    }

   [...]

    // Code to marshal (try... catch etc removed for succinctness)
   IntPtr pArrStruct = IntPtr.Zero;
   long lCount = 0;

   bool bResult = false;
   bResult = bEnumerateString(out lCount, out pArrStruct);

   if (!bResult)
   {
    // Marshal to deref pointer
       IntPtr[] pArrStructList = new IntPtr[lCount];
       for (ulong i = 0; i < (ulong)lCount; i++)
       {
            pArrStructList[i] = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pArrStruct, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) * (int)i);
       }


    // Marshal pointers to struct
       var lstMyStringStrct = new List<MY_STRUCT_STRING>(pArrStructList.Length);

       foreach (IntPtr ptr in pArrStructList)
       {         
            lstMyStringStrct.Add((MY_STRUCT_STRING)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(MY_STRUCT_STRING)));
       }

    // Enumerate struct
       foreach (MY_STRUCT_STRING myStr in lstMyStringStrct)
       {
           // All of these outputs are garbage
           Console.WriteLine("strMyString1: " + myStr.strMyString1);
           Console.WriteLine("strMyString2: " + myStr.strMyString2);
           Console.WriteLine("strMyString3: " + myStr.strMyString3);
        }

    }
```

Comment: LPWSTR is a wchar_t[], not a wchar_t*.  Remove the [MarshalAs] attribute.  And note the memory leak, nobody is calling free() for you.  You can only get ahead by using CoTaskMemAlloc() in your native code instead of malloc() or by exposing a function that calls free().

Comment: @HansPassant - Removing the MarshalAs attribute causes Marshal.PtrToStructure to throw an AccessViolation exception.

Would using CoTaskMemAlloc() help? I haven't got to freeing the memory because I'm trying to troubleshoot with a narrower scope, though would freeing the memory help the marshaling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one problem. You're C++ structure uses LPWSTR (pointers) whereas you're C# code is expecting fixed size char arrays.

Change your strings from:

```
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
public string strMyString1;
```

which would be used when the C++ structure was defined like:

```
char strMyString1[8];
```

to:

```
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public string strMyString1;
```

Comment: That's what I first thought, however using that attribute causes an ExecutionEngineException with Marshal.PtrToStructure

Comment: Turns out I had some screwup copying pointers rather than doing a wcscpy_s which was causing this to work in a Win32 console app (as the pointer was still in scope) but fail once it was inside a DLL and being marshaled into managed code.